# Algebraic calculation steps.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Can somebody explain how the coefficients $a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{22}$ are derived after rotating the ellipse below ??

$\widetilde{s_{11}} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n(x_{jk} - \bar{x_k})}{n}$

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't put the education tag back. If this is a question about education, then every question on this website is a question about education.

Comment: If it is so, the tag should not exist for a tag.

Comment: @user122358: Gerry is going by contradiction, trying to explain why the tag is not appropriate for the question, by explaining that if it were, some ridiculous thing would be true, so it's not. I will take the direct route: (education) is meant to be used for questions that are about teaching itself. [Admittedly, it's not always used that way; folks at MSE are not great about cleaning our tags when they get that many questions in them.]

Comment: I still don't understand that why I can't use the tag "education" to get some maths explanation. Is that because my question doesn't look appropriate to the tag by Gerry's judgement?? If Gerry says "don't put the education tag back" again, then I can never use the tag for this question ever again??

Comment: First of all, there isn't any "can't" here. You can use whatever tag you want to. If you insist on using the "education" tag, I'll keep deleting it. Sooner or later someone (probably me) will flag the post for moderator's attention, and a moderator will slap one of us down. Second, please read what @Eric has written about the proper use of the "education" tag.  It simply isn't appropriate for your question. Your question is about analytic geometry, or statistics, or something, but it isn't about education.

Comment: What confused me was that the way you explained yourself in the first place. If I had any reason why I can't use the "education" tag, I wouldn't have used it at all, if you look at your commend in this thread, you will understand how short your description was for me to understand the way it is here. Anyway, thank you for your time and sorry for having had your attention for no valuable thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets assume that the data are mean-centered so that the rotation is about the origin.  If the data are not in this condition we can always do the centering before we proceed.  This simplifies the path to the result we're looking for, since we can now assume that $\bar{x_.1}$ and $\bar{x_.2}$ are $0$.

Next, you'll want your variance (covariance) calculations to be based on a sum of squared deviations so that

$$\widetilde{s_{11}} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n(x_{j1} - \bar{x_{.1}})^2}{n} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^nx_{j1}^2}{n}$$

since we are assuming the means are zero.  Similarly, define $\widetilde{s_{22}}$ and $\widetilde{s_{12}}$ as $$ \widetilde{s_{22}} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^nx_{j2}^2}{n}$$ and $$\widetilde{s_{12}} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^nx_{j1}x_{j2}}{n}$$ where $\widetilde{s_{12}}$ is the sample covariance.

Using the relations between rotated and original coordinates shown above we see for a rotated point $\widetilde{P_k}$ that
$$\widetilde{x_{k1}}^2 = (x_{k1}cos\theta + x_{k2}sin\theta)^2 $$
$$= x_{k1}^2cos^2\theta + 2x_{k1}x_{k2}cos\theta sin\theta + x_{k2}^2sin^2\theta$$
and that $\widetilde{x_{k2}}^2 = x_{k1}^2sin^2\theta - 2x_{k1}x_{k2}sin\theta cos\theta + x_{k2}^2cos^2\theta$.

We can expand $\widetilde{s_{11}}$ in the same way giving $$\widetilde{s_{11}} = 
\frac{\sum_{j=1}^nx_{j1}^2}{n}$$
$$= \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n(x_{j1}cos\theta + x_{j2}sin\theta)^2}{n}$$
$$= \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n(x_{j1}^2cos^2\theta + 2x_{j1}x_{j2}cos\theta sin\theta +x_{j2}^2sin^2\theta)}{n}$$
$$=cos^2\theta s_{11} + 2cos\theta sin\theta s_{12} + sin^2\theta s_{22}$$ by regrouping and simply noticing that we're now talking about variances and the covariance in terms of the original $x$ values. Similarly, we can show that
$$ \widetilde{s_{22}} =  sin^2\theta s_{11} - 2sin\theta cos\theta s_{12} + cos^2\theta s_{22}$$

Finally, putting it all together we have that

$$\frac{\widetilde{x_{k1}}^2}{\widetilde{s_{11}}} + \frac{\widetilde{x_{k2}}^2}{\widetilde{s_{22}}}$$
$$=\frac{x_{k1}^2cos^2\theta + 2x_{k1}x_{k2}cos\theta sin\theta + x_{k2}^2sin^2\theta}{cos^2\theta s_{11} + 2cos\theta sin\theta s_{12} + sin^2\theta s_{22}} + \frac{x_{k1}^2sin^2\theta - 2x_{k1}x_{k2}sin\theta cos\theta + x_{k2}^2cos^2\theta}{sin^2\theta s_{11} - 2sin\theta cos\theta s_{12} + cos^2\theta s_{22}}.$$

If you rearrange terms in this sum you should easily be able to get to the definitions of $a_{11}, a_{12}$, and $a_{22}$ as shown above.  Take its square root and you'll have your statistical distance $d(O,P_k)$ from the unrotated point $P_k$ to the origin, taking in to account the covariance between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and valuable explanation.